# Select date and year only SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sum

I have an SQLite database structured like so:

```
ID      Date              Time           Cost
"1" "2016-05-14"    "17:39:35.925973"   "1.98"
"2" "2016-05-14"    "17:39:54.181083"   "2.84"
"3" "2016-05-14"    "17:40:26.408492"   "2.99"
"4" "2016-05-14"    "17:41:28.197353"   "3.39"
"25"    "2016-05-19"    "14:44:27.235790"   "2.5"
"26"    "2016-05-19"    "14:46:35.177696"   "1.58"
"27"    "2016-05-19"    "14:49:12.902651"   "0.1"   
"28"    "2016-05-20"    "21:35:32.446997"   "2.25"
```

I would like to sum the costs by the month and the year, disregarding the day.

I am doing this in python, but I do not even know the sqlite code to select just the month and year.

I tried this code:

```
def SumByMonth():
    usrDate = raw_input('Enter yymm: ')
    dateyear = datetime.datetime.strptime(usrDate, "%y%m").date()
    month_sql = '''SELECT cost FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%m%y', date) = ( ?  )'''
    month_price = [t[0] for t in cur.execute(month_sql, ( dateyear,) )]
    sum_total = sum(month_price)
    print 'sum is for', dateyear,'is', sum_total
```

All I get back is `sum is for 2016-05-01 is 0` so it appears it is selecting the first day of the month in absence of providing a day. How can I just select the month and year?

Thanks

Comment: You have your months and years in different orders. And I'm not sure why you're converting usrDate into a datetime; why not pass the string directly to the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a format specifier for a 2-digit year. Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

And, as @DanielRoseman mentions:

1. you are mixing up your years and months, and
2. you're unnecessarily converting the string to a datetime.

Instead do:

```
def SumByMonth():
    yyyymm = raw_input('Enter yyyymm: ')
    month_sql = '''SELECT cost FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%Y%m',date) = ?'''
    month_price = [t[0] for t in cur.execute(month_sql,(yyyymm,))]
    sum_total = sum(month_price)
    print 'sum is for', yyyymm,'is', sum_total
```

More succintly you can do:

```
def SumByMonth():
    yyyymm = raw_input('Enter yyyymm: ')
    month_sql = '''SELECT SUM(cost) FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%Y%m',date) = ?'''
    sum_total = cur.execute(month_sql,(yyyymm,)).fetchone()[0]
    print 'sum is for', yyyymm,'is', sum_total
```

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.